# Why do I need to install Wireshark GUI separately with CentOS but not with Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

What is the difference? what is the entity that makes Wireshark gets installed under Ubuntu with Wireshark GUI but it does not do that with CentOS?

Ubuntu command to Install Wireshark

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

CentOS command to Install Wireshark

```
yum -y install wireshark
yum -y install wireshark-gnome
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, both Debian/Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS package the Wireshark GUI separately from the rest of the program files, but they use different package names. In Debian, there's [`libwireshark5`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libwireshark5) containing a code library that can be used by other programs, [`wireshark-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wireshark-dev) containing files needed to compile code that uses the Wireshark library, [`wireshark-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wireshark-doc) containing some documentation, [`wireshark-common`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wireshark-common) containing some data files used by Wireshark code, [`tshark`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/tshark) containing the command-line interface, and [`wireshark-gtk`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wireshark-gtk) and [`wireshark-qt`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wireshark-qt) containing two graphical interfaces. In RHEL, there's a smaller set of packages: a package called `wireshark` containing the command line interface as well as the library and the common files (about equivalent to Debian's `wireshark-common` plus `libwireshark5` plus `tshark`), and a package `wireshark-gnome` containing the GUI.

The reason Debian packages the library separately is so that you can install multiple versions of the library simultaneously, and you can install just the library but not the program if you only want the library for some other program that uses it. This is necessary if you have programs installed that were compiled against different versions of the library with a different binary interface (ABI). That's why the name of the library package contains a version number in Debian: Debian's package system doesn't support installing multiple versions of a package with the same name. That way, if there's a new `libwireshark6` then you can install it but keep `libwireshark5` for your programs that haven't switched yet.

Generally speaking Debian splits packages into small units: if someone might reasonably want to install part X of a software but not part Y then X and Y are placed in separate packages. Most distributions don't split packages so much. But RHEL does arrange to package GUI versions separately so that you don't have to waste a lot of space on GUI libraries on a GUIless machine.